# R: Removing multiple columns from data frame based on vector values

Tags: r, vector

I have a data frame dataGL_all:

```
Date<-c("01-01-15 04:00","01-01-15 04:20","01-01-15 04:40")
FLIin<-c(96,39,72)
FLIout<-c(173,147,103)
FBEin<-c(96,116,166)
FBEout<-c(32,53,120)
dataGL_all<-data.frame(Date, FLIin, FLIout, FBEin, FBEout)
```

Furthermore, I have a vector:

```
Remove <- c("FBEin", "FLIout")
```

I would a piece of code that removes the columns in the vector Remove from the data frame dataGL_all. I have tried many combinations of functions (e.g. grep(), c() and names()) but can't get it working ... would appreciate help :) thx

P.S. My "real" data frame contains 68 columns where of I would like to remove 36 (the ones in the vector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add some more possibilities, with `data.table` package these kind of operation are very simple. You can either temporarily remove columns using `!` and `with = FALSE` combination. Or you can modify your data set by reference while evaluating this vector using `()` within `data.table` environment and assigning `NULL` to it using `:=` assignment operator, so here goes:

Load the package and convert to a `data.table` class

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataGL_all)
```

Then either do

```
dataGL_all[, !Remove, with = FALSE]
#              Date FLIin FBEout
# 1: 01-01-15 04:00    96     32
# 2: 01-01-15 04:20    39     53
# 3: 01-01-15 04:40    72    120
```

Or update the data set by reference

```
dataGL_all[, (Remove) := NULL][]
#              Date FLIin FBEout
# 1: 01-01-15 04:00    96     32
# 2: 01-01-15 04:20    39     53
# 3: 01-01-15 04:40    72    120
```

Answer (score 5):

```
dataGL_all[, !names(dataGL_all) %in% Remove]
```

should do the trick. Or, if you want `grep`:

```
dataGL_all[, grep(paste(Remove, collapse = "|"), names(dataGL_all), invert = T)]
```

Comment: It does! Thx lukA. The site tells me that I have to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer ...